# Whitelisting access to a single table

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions

Is it possible to whitelist access to a specific table (for example containing password hashes plus salts)?

My ideal situation would be zero permissions for anyone with access to insert, update, delete and select achieved through stored procedures.

How do I go about setting this up?

Comment: using roles and permissions

Comment: Could you explain a bit more for someone who spends very little time working with the sql server? Perhaps sample code?

Answer (score 7):

Access to databases in SQL Server is managed mainly through two principals:

- Logins - Security principal that allows access to the instance.
- Users - Security principal linked to a login that allows access to a specific database.

By default, SQL Server follows the practice of [least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege), meaing that when you create these principals (further documentation on that [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx)), they have minimal access to a database and the objects within that database.  Initially, these principals will only be able to connect to an instance or database but nothing else, such as selecting or modifying data.

This means that you, as an administrator, will need to [`GRANT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx) permissions to principals that need access.  For example, if you had a table and you wanted to give a user the ability to read data on that table:

```
GRANT SELECT ON table_foo TO user_bar;
```

Once this is in place, your user can select from `table_foo`, but do nothing else.  You can further grant additional permissions to other users as necessary, or `REVOKE/DENY` permissions as well.  See [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2894/understanding-grant-deny-and-revoke-in-sql-server/) for further explanation of this.

Finally, you can leverage [roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669065.aspx) to additionally manage your security.  Roles are essentially containers that have permissions granted to them and you can assign users to these roles, much like Active Directory groups.  SQL Server has several [server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188659.aspx) and [database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189121.aspx) roles that are available by default and are commonly used, but you can also create custom database level roles and assign specific permissions to those roles.

Overall, database security is a large topic that is outside the scope of a StackExchange answer, but the basic idea is you can manage a "whitelist" by assigning specific permissions on your database objects and tightly controlling the security around those objects.